# Is it possible to have an Apple Genius replace my Fusion drive with an SSD in my iMac?

Tags: mac, ssd, fusion-drive, apple-store

Can I take my iMac to an Apple store and have the Geniuses replace its Fusion drive with a pure SSD?

Comment: You should ask them since we cannot speak for Apple in this context.  That said, see relevant answer for more info:  https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239723/119271

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes and no.

If it's under warranty, then it's a definite **no**, even if you're willing to pay for it.

If it's not under warranty, the answer gets a little more complicated because it depends on the exact model of iMac, its status (i.e. is it considered by Apple to be *vintage* or *obsolete*), and to some degree to your location.

**The best answer we can give here is that you need to contact your nearest Apple Store and ask them.**

My advice would be that if it is under warranty, to just leave things as they are. If it's a real issue for you, then you may have other options (such as using an external SSD as your boot drive, etc).

Comment: *If it's under warranty, then it's a definite no, even if you're willing to pay for it.*  Why?  The [Magnuson-Moss Warranty Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act) protects the consumer in this case.

Comment: @Allan I confess I'm not familiar with that Act (obviously because I'm based in Australia, not the US), but my understanding is that except in the case of RAM, Apple won't modify the hardware configuration of a Mac while it's still under warranty. At least that's the case here in Australia. That is, they will replace hardware if/when necessary, but that hardware needs to meet the same specs. The *only* exception to this (besides RAM) is when Apple replaces hardware with something of better specs because they need to rectify a fault etc under warranty or an exchange or extended repair program.

Comment: I'm curious though, what part of the [Magnuson-Moss Warranty Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnuson%E2%80%93Moss_Warranty_Act) were you referring to in this case? Although, when I get a chance later, I'll read the entire article anyway.

Comment: The Act basically states that you can modify/upgrade your product without voiding the warranty meaning you can upgrade the hardware (like HDD) and not invalidate the warranty if the GPU fails.  That said, I wouldn't take anything to a "Genius."  I've gotten more wrong info from them - at least here in the States.

Comment: Sounds like my kind of Act! And yeah, I've come across my fair share of *Geniuses* who don't necessarily know what they're talking about. Much better to say *I don't know* or *I'll have to check* then to put it on. As for the OP's question and the Act, I don't think Apple argues that you'd invalidate the warranty by doing the upgrade (although they certainly won't cover something if the *upgrade* or the *act* of upgrading caused a problem), just that they themselves won't change the specs of a Mac during the warranty period. I'd be surprised if this was different in the US, but it may well be.

Comment: I've found the warranties on Macs are useless.  Recalls have been helpful (like this latest one with the batteries).  I see finding a good tech analogous to finding a good mechanic - 9 times out of 10 they aren't certified by the factory and do a better job.  +1 for emphasizing the OP needs to contact the store directly to ask.

Comment: @Allan both times I have had to have Apple do warrantee work they have been exemplary, way better than other companies - they even did all the transport for free - in both directions...

Answer (score 2):

M-M prohibits manufacturers from requiring that repairs or maintenance be done by authorized service centers using OEM parts and supplies in order for the product's warranty to remain in effect. While customer-initiated product changes unrelated to a failure don't invalidate warranty coverage on other parts of a covered mechanism, M-M does not require manufacturers to upgrade or change their products at customer request, even if the customer is willing to pay for the work.

The "no" that the OP will hear is because Apple chooses not to modify its products still under warranty. This is a rational position. The OP must either wait until the warranty is over (in which case an Apple service center or store *might* do the work), or take the Mac to to a non-Apple provider, or do the work on his own.