# How do I check the hardware of my iMac?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a late 2012 iMac that I suspect has something failing in terms of disk or USB.

This is what is happening:

1. Some programs freeze from times to times. Once that happens, there is no way for the program to run again. Just a restart of the iMac will solve that.
2. WHen #1 happens the computer fails to shutdown. I have to force shutdown.
3. I have 4 USB external drives connected to a USB HUB that is connected to the Mac. From times to times, all these disks disconnect.
4. I am unable to boot in diagnostic mode. Restarting the computer with D pressed makes the computer reach a white page that does not go anywhere. Restarting the computer with Option D (diagnostics over internet) shows a screen that appears to be loading something. It takes centuries for the progress bar to advance 1/100 of a pixel. For the pace of that progress bar I estimate 8 hours just to show the diagnostic screen, if anything is loading at all.
5. Restarting the computer in recovery mode over internet, shows the spinning globe. Same thing, slow as hell. I estimate 2h just to show the recovery screen.

I am suspecting the disk is failing. That late 2012 iMac uses a spinning disk that I suspect is going bad. All fsck to that disk shows two, what I think is bad sectors. The SMART screen shows nothing wrong with the disk.

But, running `smartctl` shows me this for the `Macintosh HD`.

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     APPLE HDD WDC WD10EALX-408EA0
Firmware Version: 07.01D03
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu May 28 00:34:24 2020 WEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (16800) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 194) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0xb037) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   181   173   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3933
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       9305
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   065   065   000    Old_age   Always       -       26100
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       9284
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   192   192   000    Old_age   Always       -       6185
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       3115
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   095   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       52
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               10%     21652         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

and for the `Macintosh HD - Data`:

```
=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     APPLE HDD WDC WD10EALX-408EA0
Firmware Version: 07.01D03
User Capacity:    1,000,204,886,016 bytes [1.00 TB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu May 28 00:33:11 2020 WEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (16800) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 194) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   5) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0xb037) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       1
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0027   181   173   021    Pre-fail  Always       -       3933
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       9305
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   200   200   140    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002e   100   253   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   065   065   000    Old_age   Always       -       26100
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   091   091   000    Old_age   Always       -       9284
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   192   192   000    Old_age   Always       -       6185
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   199   199   000    Old_age   Always       -       3115
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   095   093   000    Old_age   Always       -       52
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0032   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x0008   200   200   000    Old_age   Offline      -       18

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               10%     21652         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

But I am not sure if I understand these enigmatic reports.

Do these numbers make sense as a failing disk?

Comment: I’d bet its a drive issue given that you’ve got an 8 year old drive in there.  The SMART Info you posted is just whether it’s supported/enabled.  Start with `diskutil info disk1 | grep -i smart` if it says anything but “Verified” it’s failing.  However, it might pass but still be bad.  If you get “Verified” run a more comprehensive test like [DiskDrill][https://www.cleverfiles.com/) for a full test

Comment: I’m actually still using my 2012 iMac after fixing my failed HDD.  See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/239723/119271.  Fusion drives are tricky, so let me know if you need a walk through on setting it up for Mojave or Catalina

Comment: It says Verified but like you said, this is an 8 years old disk in there. As far as I know this Late 2012 has no PCIe, so I am not able to put a blade SSD in there. I have purchased the OWC kit with the sensor for the disk and I am buying a 2TB SSD to replace the spinning disk. I will go full SSD. I am wondering how much fast the computer will be.

Comment: Do `diskutil list` to confirm.  Also run DiskDrill diagnostics.  It’s free.

Comment: @SteveChambers - I say on my question that this does not work for me.

Comment: Sorry, deleted...