# Installed Mac OS on external drive but OS updates install onto the internal drive

Tags: macos, startup, ssd, external-disk

I want to install the latest Mac OS on an external NVME SSD. My old fusion drive is running slow.

However, in the past whenever I've done this, ive found that whenever there was an OS update my Mac would get confused and sometimes install the update on the internal fusion drive and boot from that.

Is there a way to prevent this so my Mac ONLY recognises my external drive as the boot drive?

Thank you all very much for your help in advance,

Comment: What macOS version are you using?

Comment: Hi - I will be using Mac Ventura - in the past I had the issue with Mac Catalina -

Comment: I am deducing that you are on Monterey since you *will* use Ventura?

Comment: Is your Fusion dive still operational with a valid image of macOS installed?  How are you booting your Mac, automatically or holding `Opt` to access the boot manager?

Comment: [You should *fix* your Fusion drive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/238093/119271). Booting from an external drive is like driving your car on the spare tire,  yes, you can do it, but it wasn’t designed for prolonged use; it’s for short term use until you get things sorted.

Comment: No that's incorrect Allan - the speed difference you gain from an external nvme is enormous

Comment: Is this NVME SSD a 5 Gb/s USB, 10 Gb/s USB, Thunderbolt 3 or something else?